# Fastest way to search for multiple strings in multiple large text files

Tags: c#, string, performance, file

What is the fastest technology/algorithm that can be implemented in order to lookup list of strings in a quite large text files (Up to 1GB text files).
For starters, I'm using C# and was able to achieve the logic (Simply by matching a file with list of strings, string by string every time. Which means that the file will be read *n* number of strings to match with" times), but since I'm dealing with a lot of files, it is taking forever running through them and get matches.
I'm open to any suggestion even if it was not C#.

To elaborate more, I have a text file that contains many numbers(A), and I have a lot of large files(B). I'm trying to take every element in (A) and see if there is a match for it in (B) line by line. If there is a match I write the whole line into a text file. The way I'm doing it is really traditional and it takes a lot of time to get done with a single file, while I have hundreds of them with sizes up to 1GB.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Comment: What do you mean by match? I can think of multiple ways of doing this  that do not require repeated readings of the input file. Please supply examples of successful and unsuccessful searches. Also what are the orders of magnitude of the file size and the list of strings?

Comment: I would try to read as large a chunk as possible form a file and do all searche in memory on it. Then move back by the size of ther largest string you search and read the next chunk..

Comment: @DavidHarris I'm doing the following: I have a text file that contains many numbers(A), and I have a lot of large files(B). I'm trying to take every element in (A) and see if there is a match for it in (B) line by line. If there is a match I write the whole line into a text file. 
The way I'm doing it is really traditional and it takes a lot of time to get done with a single file, while I have hundreds of them with sizes up to 1GB

Comment: Given this information, I'd use a C# HashSet<T> to store the A numbers. If the current line in B contains any of the numbers in the set, I'd add this line to the output file. In this way each file is read only once.

Comment: @DavidHarris Good call, but that won't make any difference when I won't find any match at all. Correct?

Comment: Correct. If you don't find a match, the input line is dropped and will not appear in the output file.

Comment: You should put the specifics you are mentioning in the comments into the question, along with any code you have so far

Comment: Does the order things are written to the output file matter?

Comment: @konkked nope they don't matter all I need to find is the matches and print them out to text file

Comment: How in the world was this question closed as "too broad?" The question is pretty specific, and there is at least one well-known solution to the problem that doesn't take a huge amount of effort to explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to implement the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). It reads the file one time and finds all occurrences of all the strings you give it. See https://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=869 for an article that provides an implementation and some examples.

### Update after more info

Assuming that the list of numbers in your file A is small enough to fit in memory, here's what you'd do, using the implementation in the above-linked article:

```
// Construct the automaton
AhoCorasickStringSearcher matcher = new AhoCorasickStringSearcher();
foreach (var searchWord in File.ReadLines(File_a)
{
    matcher.AddItem(searchWord);
}
matcher.CreateFailureFunction();

// And then do the search on each file
foreach (var fileName in listOfFiles)
{
    foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
        var matches = matcher.Search(line);
        foreach (m in matches)
        {
            // output match
        }
    }
}
```

Note that it only makes one pass through each file, and it never has to load more than one line of the file into memory at any time. The limiting factor here is the memory it takes to build the automaton.

I've used this to search files that totaled over 100 gigabytes, for about 15 million different strings. It takes a few minutes to build the automaton, but then it searches very quickly. One really nice property of the algorithm is that its complexity is O(n + m), where n is the size of the input files, and m is the number of matched items. The number of strings it's searching for doesn't matter. It can search for a million different strings just as quickly as it can search for one or two.

100 gigabytes will take you ... something on the order of about 40 minutes to read. I'd be really surprised if it took an hour for this to find all occurrences of 15 million different strings in 100 gigabytes of data.

### Matching whole words

Another option, if you're searching for whole words is to ditch the Aho-Corasick algorithm. Instead, load all of the numbers you're looking for into a `HashSet<string>`. Then read each line and use a regular expression to find all of the numbers in the line and check to see if they exist in the hash set. For example:

```
Regex re = new Regex("\w+");
foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(filename))
{
    var matches = re.Matchs(line);
    foreach (var m in matches)
    {
        if (hashSetOfValues.Contains(m))
        {
            // output match
        }
    }
}
```

This will likely be somewhat slower than the Aho-Corasick algorithm, but it still makes only one pass through the data. This assumes, of course, that you have enough memory to hold all of those numbers in a hash set.

There are other options for whole words, as I mention in the comments.

Another option, if you know that the words you're looking for are always separated by spaces, is to add spaces to the start and end of the words that you add to the automaton. Or, with some modification to the implementation itself, you could force the matcher's `Search` method to only return matches that occur in whole words. That could more easily handle matches at the start and end of lines, and additional non-word characters.

Comment: Thank you Jim, I'm going to give it a shot and see how it goes

Comment: I just tried it and it worked like charm ... Thank you so much Jim this is truly amazing!

Comment: Really appreciate that. One more thing, I'm trying to match a list of files in a specific directory and I have not been able to do so without using "Stream Reader" is there any other way to do so?

Comment: after running the script multiple times, it seems that the algorithm doesn't do whole string match only but also does substring matches too. Is that correct?

Comment: @WT86: You are correct. If your search term is "be", it will match on that string anywhere. So it will find "be" in "believe" and in "unbelievable." If you want whole words only, there are two simple ways to do it. The first would be to post-process the line and check to see if the match is on a whole word. The other would be to break the line into words, run each word through the automaton, and if it returns a match check that it's a whole word match. The first of those is probably faster and easier.

Comment: @WT86 Also, what problem are you having with the directory? You should be able to call `Directory.GetFiles` to get a list of the files you want, and then call `File.ReadLines` on each of the file names returned, just as I showed in the example.

Comment: @WT86: See my update. I added some information about matching whole words.

Comment: Once again thank you a lot :) I went ahead and used HashSet to save my file that I want to match, and then applied Regular Expression to get a whole match just like what you said and so far the results look good.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (string  _row in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(AddressFilePath))
{
  if(_row.Contains(TextToSearch)){
     //Do something
     Console.WriteLine(_row);
  }
}
```

Comment: That has the drawback of crashing if the file is too large to fit into memory. In addition, you'd have to search the entire text multiple times.

Comment: I'm doing almost the same, but this is not an efficient way to deal with very large files where you have to scan line by line