# How to copy a specific part of a text file

Tags: c#, .net, text

My goal is to copy specific contents of .txt files into 1 big text file. I've searched through the website and found a way to merge my files.

```
using (var output = File.Create("output"))
{
    foreach (var file in new[] { "file1", "file2" })
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            input.CopyTo(output);
        }
    }
}
```

This answer was posted by: n8wrl

The structure of my text looks like this:

> ...
>
> Sentence A
>
> Important stuff
>
> Sentence B
>
> ...

So I would need a way to search for `"Sentence A"` and `"Sentence B"` in the document and copy the lines between these two.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use [`File.ReadLines()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(v=vs.110).aspx), then you can use Linq to query the data

Comment: Implement Stream wrapper which seeks to specific sentence end and then reads all relevant part until another sentence beginning....or do simple line-by-line with ReadLine thing to identify required positions.

Comment: @bommelding it is less then 1MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that both `"Sentence A"` and `"Sentence B"` are in *whole lines* you can try a simple *Linq*. Let's extract the "important stuff" first:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Staff(string file) 
{
    return File
        .ReadLines(file)
        .SkipWhile(line => line != "Sentence A")  // Skip until Sentence A found 
        .Skip(1)                                  // Skip Sentence A itself
        .TakeWhile(line => line != "Sentence B"); // Take until Sentence B found 
}
```

Then combine all the files into one:

```
string[] files = new[] 
{
    "file1", "file2", "file3"
};

var extracts = files.SelectMany(file => Staff(file));
```

finally, let's write all the `extracts` into the file:

```
File.WriteAllLines("output", extracts);
```

**Edit:** In case you have *merged* files ("important stuff" can appear *several* times) we have to implement *FSM* (Finite State Machine):

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Staff(string file) 
{
    bool important = false;

    foreach (string line in file.ReadLines(file)) 
    {
        if (important) 
            if (line == "Sentence B")
                important = false;
            else
                yield return line;
        else 
            important = line == "Sentence B"; 
    }
}
```

Please, notice that we have to scan the *entire* file, that's why we should avoid file merging.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you think it would be more beneficial to extract the important stuff from each file first and then make one file out of them or merge the files first and then do the extranction? Because "Sentence A" and "Sentence B" appear once in each file.

Comment: @Botond: In the code above I process file after file; I doubt if it's beneficial to merge files into one: as you can see I've exploited the fact that staff appears only ones (`Skip...Take`); if files are merged we have to implement *FSM* (Finite State Machine) with two states: in/out of the staff. Another drawback is that we want to leave the file as early as we can (imagine that the important staff is in the top of each file) whch we can't do if files are merged

Comment: I understand now. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the options from this post: [Fastest way to search string in large text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37979457/fastest-way-to-search-string-in-large-text-file) to locate what you want for the start and end sentence, use those positions (start of first and end of second) in a substring.

Make sure you test for the situations where the second sentence appears before the first, where it appears twice (do you want the text between the first sentence and the second occurrence of the second sentence?) and where there is no second sentence. Then consider similar scenarios for the first sentence (e.g. if it appears after the second sentence, if it appears more than once, and if it doesn't appear at all while the second sentence is present).

Comment: The only case it appears is first sentence then second sentece. It happens multiple times in the merged text file because it happens once each text file that i merged! Thanks for the answer I'm searching through the post you linked!

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
var sentenceA = "Sentence A";
var sentenceB = "Sentence B";
using (var output = System.IO.File.Create("output"))
{
    foreach (var file in new[] { "file1", "file2" })
    {
        using (var input = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(input);
            var text = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToString();
            if (text.Contains(sentenceA) && text.Contains(sentenceB)) {
                output.Write(text.Substring(text.IndexOf(sentenceA), text.IndexOf(sentenceB) + sentenceB.Length));
            }
        }
    }
}
```